# VBA Word Doc won't close on certain computers or with certain versions of Word

Tags: vba, excel

In an Excel vba program, I have a function which returns a string of document text from a Word document. It works on every computer I've tried except my work laptop. On my work laptop, it cannot close the Word document.

The following code works on my home computers with Word 2011, and a workstation with Word 2010, but not on my work laptop with Word 2013. When run on my work laptop, the program gets hung up on doc.Close.

I've checked that all the references/libraries I need are enabled (Word Object libraries, Excel Object libraries, Microsoft Office Object libraries). I'm banging my head against the wall with this. Here's the code:

```
Private Function getDocText(filePath As String) As String
 Dim host As New Word.Application
 Dim doc As Word.Document
 Dim doctext As String

 Set doc = host.Documents.Open(filePath)    
 doctext = doc.Content.Text

 doc.Close
 host.Quit

 getDocText = doctext
End Function
```

Comment: Try open in **ReadOnly** mode `.Open(FileName:=filepath, ReadOnly:=True)`?

Comment: Often, when something like this happens, the Office application is displaying a message requesting user input/decision. You apparently don't set `host.Visible = True` so you're not seeing the Word window? Try putting that line in and see what Word is doing...

Comment: None of these suggestions fixed the problem. For some reason this code will not complete on my work laptop.

Comment: I've since spoken with an expert who has concluded that MS Office products were installed on our laptops in such a way as to prevent VBA scripts from opening and closing programs automatically (for security).